# AttributeError: 'ResourceSummaryWriter' object has no attribute 'get_logdir'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to run some code written in tensorflow v1.0 in tensorflow 2.1 library package. So I have to rewrite some of the code. I have been facing some problem with one line of the codes

```
LOG_DIR='./'
summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(LOG_DIR)
```

now I understand that in v2.0, tf.summary has been deprecated and I was to write the new code instead

```
summary_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(LOG_DIR)
```

but whenever i start to run

```
logdir = summary_writer.get_logdir()
```

It gives me an error of

```
AttributeError: 'ResourceSummaryWriter' object has no attribute 'get_logdir'
```

I search around and found no solution. What can be the problem? Isn't it just stating the LOG_DIR (which I have done)

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, after a long struggling with that, I just solved it. 
I just modified the core source  "~tensorboard/plugins/projector/**init**.py"
I got rid of lines 'logdir' and pass the log file path to "summary_writer"

> ------------------ "~tensorboard/plugins/projector/**init**.py----------------------

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKRBS.png)

> ------------------ myapp.py--------------------------------

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1FCC.png)

Comment: tensorflow 1.14, tensorboard 1.14